# multi-line sed expression doesnt work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to insert specific xml configuration inside a specific xml element in a configuration file with sed in a bash shell script. When using the sed command on one line it works but when the expression is on multiple lines, it doesnt.

I'm trying to insert the xml configuration inside the  element which is almost in the middle of the file so i was using the line to test sed 's//\nconfig/gi' file.xml and that works, but i need to add a lot more configuration, so the resulting sed command is like this:

```
sed -i '
/broker/broker\n \
    <plugins> \
        <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq" /> \
        <authorizationPlugin> \
            <map> \
                <authorizationMap> \
                    <authorizationEntries> \
                        <authorizationEntry topic=> read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" /> \
                        <authorizationEntry queue=> read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" /> \
                    </authorizationEntries> \
                </authorizationMap> \
            </map> \
        </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>/' $ACTIVEMQ_CONFIG
```

I originally wrote this as a here document in bash, but it turns out that the sed command itself needs escaping/line continuation character anyway so it didnt help much with having a prettier code.

The command above gives me the error message "unterminated address regex" and i cant really see the reason why since its basically sed 's/pattern/replace/' which is the syntax. If im adding the s/ to the start of the sed command i just get a message saying that the s was not terminated properly.

I have been searching for quite some time to try to figure how to manage multiple line seds script and i though i was just going to write a sed script but then i need another script as well in addition to the shell script and im not sure i would want that just for a configuration change, it seems a little overkill.

Comment: `</authorizationPlugin>` needs \

Comment: You are using forward slashes as your sed delimiter, but there are forward slashes in your replacement text as well. What if you replace the sed slashes with something else - eg `sed -i 's#broker#broker\n etc#'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should better store your XML snippet in a temp file and then use this simple sed with `r` command:

```
sed -i.bak '/broker/r _temp' file.xml
```

Where `_temp` is this:

```
cat _temp
<plugins>
    <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq" />
    <authorizationPlugin>
        <map>
            <authorizationMap>
                <authorizationEntries>
                  <authorizationEntry topic=> read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
                  <authorizationEntry queue=> read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
                </authorizationEntries>
            </authorizationMap>
        </map>
    </authorizationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: that seems a lot cleaner, thanks for informing me about it, ill check out the r command for next time, but for now i think ill just go with the escaping or just another delimiter

Comment: Sure its your call. If I am doing it then I would keep my script simple to read and something that can be maintained for future changes as well.

Comment: ill do it like you mentioned, the script will be a lot easier to read like you say. i guess ill just create a subdir with the config. also liked the -i with the .bak argument. seemed a little unnecessary at the time but when having to do this with multiple configs it does clean up a bit and make it at lot easier to edit the xml as well.

Comment: I am glad you liked it.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments the forward slash as the delimiter is taking the hard road. Generally, however, you need to prefix with `s` (you say so in the question, but then omit it in the regex), otherwise sed will think `b` is a branching command, and you'll get the address error. Also you need to prefix every `<` and `/` with backslashes, and it's also good to escape the quotes.

Here's your regex working,

```
sed -i 's/broker/broker\n \
<plugins> \
    <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration=\"activemq\" \/> \
    <authorizationPlugin> \
        <map> \
            <authorizationMap> \
                <authorizationEntries> \
                    <authorizationEntry topic=> read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" \/> \
                    <authorizationEntry queue=> read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" \/> \
                <\/authorizationEntries> \
            <\/authorizationMap> \
        <\/map> \
    <\/authorizationPlugin> \
<\/plugins>/'
```

**[See it live](http://ideone.com/5SWyNk)**

Comment: you guys are fast :) completely missed that i was using the same character in the xml, thanks for pointing that out so quickly

Comment: sure, i just cant decide which one